# Question on the orthogonal decomposition thm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a positive definite matrix $A$ and a vector $v$, then, why does the following hold:

$$ Av = \lambda v + \eta v^\perp$$

I was first thinking that this may be due to the orth. decomp. thm., but I believe that the latter just decomposes a vector into a subspace and another vector in the orth. complement of this subspace. I am not able to generalize this to a matrix times a vector, i.e., why would the decomposition still be along $v$? Is there some connection with the eigenvalue problem to be able to write the above?

For my second Q, say I have the following inequality:

$$ D = \| v \|^2 v v^T + 2 \lambda v v^T + \eta v^\perp v^T + \eta v (v^\perp)^T \succeq 0 $$

then, is the above equivalent to

$$ D = \bigg[ (\| v \|^2 + 2 \lambda) \otimes {\bf{1}}_{1 \times 4n},\eta \otimes {\bf{1}}_{1 \times 4n},\eta \otimes {\bf{1}}_{1 \times 4n},0 \otimes {\bf{1}}_{1 \times 4n} \bigg] \begin{pmatrix}
v v^T \\
v (v^\perp)^T \\
 v^\perp v^T \\
v^\perp (v^\perp)^T \\
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0 \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
\| v \|^2 + 2 \lambda & \eta\\ 
\eta & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0$$

and ${\bf{1}}_{1 \times 4n}$ is a row vector of ones if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Then, would the above implication follow -- considering that the second matrix (of size $4n \times n$) defined in $D$ is non-zero, i.e., why can the first part of $D$ be written as a matrix?

Would appreciate any help on these two. Thank you.

Comment: What is the bar in the middle of matrices? What does it mean by $\succeq 0$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. **Any** vector can be written in the form $av + b v^\bot$ (assuming that $v^\bot$ is an element perpendicular to $v$).

Comment: @i707107 just meant the bar as a separator between the rows. I am just not sure if multiplying by a vector of matrices (i.e., the second vector of $D$) is ok? $\succeq 0$ just means that the eigenvalues are greater tan or equal to zero?

Comment: It is still not clear. So, the first matrix is $2\times 1$  matrix and the second is?

Comment: Also, we generally don't use separators when we write matrices.

Comment: Still, matrix multiplication of the two matrices is not well-defined. Also what are $\lambda$ and $\mu$?

Comment: I still don't follow what you mean. May be morning fuzziness.

Comment: @copper.hat all I am trying to say is that $A \textbf{y} = \lambda \textbf{y} + \eta \textbf{y}^\perp $ -- is this relationship unique....can't the $\textbf{y}$ on the RHS of  $A \textbf{y}$  be another vector? because the orth decomp thm does not say that the RHS vector has to be the same as the left....I just haven't seen  the orth decomp of a matrix times a vector basically and can just relate this to the eigenvalue problem so am not sure.

Comment: I still don't understand. Are you saying that for a given $A,v$ that there exists $\lambda, \eta, v^\bot$ such that the relationship holds (for that $A,v$)?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, thank you for saying it like this. can it not be the case that for a given $(A,v)$ there exists $\lambda,\eta,y,y^\perp$ (where $y$ is some other vector that is related to $A v$)? I don't see why the orth. decomp. thm. implies that "there exists $\lambda,\eta,v^\perp$". Also, would appreciate on any help with the form of $\bar{D}$. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equality is completely trivial. Given $v$, $Av$ is also a vector. If you write this vector in an orthonormal basis that has $v$ as its first vector, then 
$$
Av=\lambda v+(\alpha_1w_1+\cdots+\alpha_n),
$$
where you can take $\eta=1$.

The implication does not hold. If you take $\eta>0$, then $$ \| v \|^2 v v^T + 2 \lambda v v^T + \eta v^\perp v^T + \eta v (v^\perp)^T \succeq 0$$ but
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\| v \|^2 + 2 \lambda & \eta\\ 
\eta & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \succeq0\ \ \iff \ \ \lambda\geq\|v\|^2/2 \ \text{ and } \ \eta=0.
$$

Comment: Yes, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ then $D\succeq0$. I don't see an obvious reason for the converse to hold. Note that the choice of $v^\perp$ and $\eta$ is not canonical.